# Can i get the top layer of UITextview to get html special characters before it encoded? 

Tags: html, ipad, uitextview, special-characters, layer

i made an app that show some text in UIWebview, but the text is edited or input in UITextview. My problem is, i want to show "&lt;" and another HTML special characters in UIWebview, but when i type it in UITextview, it got something wrong. When i NSlog on textViewDidChange delegate method, the string is showed is "<"

```
2011-03-10 16:43:19.228 MyApp[4943:207] text DID CHANGE : <
```

so, the text in UIWebview always show "<". I think i have to change in some logical in textViewDidChange delegate method, but i dont know what.

Do somebody face a same case like mine??
Please share something to me.

Thank You

Regards,

Risma

**UPDATE**

sorry, i was wrong about changing logical textViewDidChange delegate method, becuase, we can change it or override this method with some code that we need.
Now i realize, that UITextview always translate "&lt;" into "<", maybe this is because UITextView have an inheritance behavior from webkit. 
And then i think, i have to find some way to encode "&lt" in that UITextview, but i'm still search the best way to do that. Is there anybody can help me??

**UPDATE**

i think there is some layer in UITextview, maybe if i can get the top layer in UITextview, i can get the "&lt;" text before it decode to be "<". But i dont know how to get it. I was try to debug UITextview, but it still didn't show the layer to me, do somebody know how to get this top layer?? And is my opinion correct??

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know if there is a way to escape it, but you maybe can tray with `&amp;lt;`

Comment: i was try that in textViewShouldChangeTextInRange delegate method using stringByReplacingOccurenceString, but before the text is replaced, it sended to textViewDidChange delgate method, and it replaced into "<"